# After cloning a repository from Bitbucket the terminal shows all files from previous directory in untracked files

Tags: git

I clone the repo to a certain directory from Bitbucket with this link

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:Sasha781/ecommpay-test.git
```

No matter how many folders I put my final directory in, after cloning the terminal always shows all the files from the home directory as untracked, and so I can't continue as I surely don't want to add them all.

Here's what I get:

```
git:(main) ✗ cd src
➜  src git:(main) ✗ mkdir Test
➜  src git:(main) ✗ cd Test
➜  Test git:(main) ✗ git clone git@bitbucket.org:Sasha781/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Counting objects: 4, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4/4), done.
➜  Test git:(main) ✗ git status
warning: could not open directory '.Trash/': Operation not permitted
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../../.498731.padl
    ../../.CFUserTextEncoding
    ../../Applications/
    ../../Desktop/
    ../../Documents/
    ../../Downloads/
    ../../Library/
    ../../Movies/
    ../../Music/
    ../../Pictures/
    ../../Public/
    ../../docs/
    ../

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
➜  Test git:(main) ✗ ls
test
```

Also doesn't matter if it is HTTPS or SSH.

I've tried creating a repo in different directories but the result is always the same. What do I do wrong?
New to Git and Bitbucket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have initialised a git repo in your home folder. Check if you have `.git` folder in your home folder and delete that `.git` folder

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. It worked, thank you!

Comment: Great, could you also mark the answer as accepted? @Sasha